# Google One Tap library fails to fallback to native credential manager when there is no Google session

Tags: google-signin, google-identity, google-one-tap

It seems like there is a bug in Google's One Tap client JS library that prevents the fallback to native credential manager when there is no Google session.

**Intended Behavior:** If there is no active Google session and the One Tap prompt is thus not displayed to the user, a fallback to the browser's native credential manager is performed. If the user has no active Google session, it can login using the saved password credentials from the credential manager. Thus, if the One Tap prompt is not shown, the browser's native credential manager is shown that lets the user pick a username/password combination. In the end, either a POST request to the `data-native_login_uri` endpoint is performed, or the callback `data-native_callback` is executed.

**Current Behavior:** As shown in the attached screenshot, instead of loading the callback with `a.native_callback`, it is loaded with `a.zc`. Of course, `a.zc` does not exist, such that the callback is set to undefined. Since there is no callback defined, the browsers native credential manager is never shown. If we change `this.F = a.native_callback` with the debugger, everything works as expected.

This bug is located in the `gis_client_library` JS library that is loaded when the Google One-tap sign-up and auto sign-in library is included on a website. In specific, this bug affects the `data-native_callback` HTML attribute of the One Tap configuration object and the `native_callback` JS parameter of the `google.accounts.id.initialize` method. My configuration object looks like the following:

```html
<div id="g_id_onload"
    data-client_id="XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    data-auto_select="false"
    data-callback="handleTokenCredential"
    data-native_callback="handlePasswordCredential"
></div>
```

Did anyone succeed in configuring the Google One Tap API with a native credentials manager as fallback?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed on Google side (as of Aug. 2020).